# Animation in google maps is causing lag / map movement when touched is slow?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation, google-maps-android-api-2

The below code can be used to make a ripple animation on the map. 
But the issue is if I leave the map with the animation running for an hour or more, there is a lag in the UI, the animation becomes very slow, some times the map itself gets stuck and moves. Its  very annoying to see the map behaving like this. So how do I make this right? How do I make the map smooth even when there is an animation running on it?

Kindly help me out with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
public void animateCircleOne(){
    if(circle_1!=null){
        valueAnimator_1.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        valueAnimator_1.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        valueAnimator_1.setIntValues(getIntStart(), getIntEnd());
        valueAnimator_1.setDuration(getDuration());
        valueAnimator_1.setStartDelay(getAnimationDelayOne());
        valueAnimator_1.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
        valueAnimator_1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator_1.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                if(circle_1!=null) {
                    circle_1.setStrokeColor(returnAlphaColor(animatedFraction));
                    circle_1.setRadius(animatedFraction * getMaxAnimationLengthOne());
                }
            }


          });
            valueAnimator_1.start();
        }
    }
/*return alpha fraction*/
    private double returnAlphaFraction(float fraction){
        double value = ALPHA * fraction;
        if(value==0){
            return 255;
        }
        return (ALPHA * fraction);
    }

    /*return animated alpha and color*/
    private int returnAlphaColor(float animatedFraction){
        return Color.argb((int)(ALPHA - returnAlphaFraction(animatedFraction)), Color_R, Color_G, Color_B);
    }
```

Comment: i've got the same problem, did you solve?

Comment: @JackTurky - Sorry to say this, even I did not find a solution